# Spring Boot + AWS S3: Unable to delete files in the bucket

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

i am new to AWS, and my first module i try to learn is S3 for file storage.

Uploading works fine, the problem is with deleting.So when i upload a file i store the string version of the name of the file in AWS bucket `mybucket` and the whole URL in mysql database like this
-> `https://mybucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/what.png`

The problem with deleting is that even if i pass the whole URL in this case `https://mybucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/what.png` to the delete method, the method goes to each steps successfully, telling me that the file has been succesfully deleted but when i check the bucket, the file is still there.I have tried searching around here for a similar issue, but couldn't find something that could help me understand what the problem is.here is the code

```
@Service
public class AmazonS3ClientServiceImpl {
    private String awsS3AudioBucket; //bucket name
    private AmazonS3 amazonS3; // s3 object which uploads file
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AmazonS3ClientServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    public AmazonS3ClientServiceImpl(Region awsRegion, AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider, String awsS3AudioBucket) {
        this.amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .withRegion(awsRegion.getName()).build();
        this.awsS3AudioBucket = awsS3AudioBucket;
    }


    public String uploadFileToS3Bucket(MultipartFile multipartFile, boolean enablePublicReadAccess) {
        String uploadedfile = ""; // the file path which is on s3
        String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();

        try {
            //creating the file in the server (temporarily)
            File file = new File(fileName);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(multipartFile.getBytes());
            fos.close();

            PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(this.awsS3AudioBucket, fileName, file);

            if (enablePublicReadAccess) {
                putObjectRequest.withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
            }
            this.amazonS3.putObject(putObjectRequest);
            uploadedfile = String.valueOf(this.amazonS3.getUrl(awsS3AudioBucket, fileName));
            System.out.println(this.amazonS3.getUrl(awsS3AudioBucket, fileName));
            System.out.println(uploadedfile);


            //removing the file created in the server
            file.delete();
        } catch (IOException | AmazonServiceException ex) {
            logger.error("error [" + ex.getMessage() + "] occurred while uploading [" + fileName + "] ");
        }
        return uploadedfile;
    }

    public void deleteFileFromS3Bucket(String fileName) {
        LOGGER.info("Deleting file with name= " + fileName);
        final DeleteObjectRequest deleteObjectRequest = new DeleteObjectRequest(this.awsS3AudioBucket, fileName);
        amazonS3.deleteObject(deleteObjectRequest);
        LOGGER.info("File deleted successfully");
    }
```

and when i call the deletemethod i use this

```
@GetMapping("/dashboard/showposts/delete/{id}")
    public String deletePost(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
        System.out.println("GOT HERE");
        //Retrieving Post image name
        Post post = postService.findBydId(id);
        String imageName = post.getImage();
        System.out.println(imageName);
        //Deleting image from S3 bucket
        amazonClient.deleteFileFromS3Bucket(imageName);
        //Deleting post from db
        postService.detelePost(id);
        String success = "Successfully deleted post with Id" + id;
        model.addAttribute("success", success);
        return "redirect:/admin/dashboard/showposts";
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**L.E** For anyone having the same issue and searching for a quick answer.You have to pass only the string image name to the delete method not the whole URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't checking the response returned from `amazonS3.deleteObject()` to see if it was actually successful or not. It is probably returning a failure status.

I'm guessing the root issue is that you are passing the full URL to the delete method, instead of just the path to the file within S3. For example with this URL: `https://mybucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/what.png` the S3 object path is simply `what.png`.

Comment: That method returns void (see the V1 docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#deleteObject-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.DeleteObjectRequest-))

Comment: yes i just checked that out to, the method returns void. I could indeed check with passing it what.png, but how can i do that when i save the whole URL in the mysql db column like this ```https://mybucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/what.png``` and when i call the getImage() method it returns this whole URL.How can i sepparate file name from URL?

Comment: That's a bit of a different question - how to parse out the parts of the URL.

Comment: Ok, i can confirm, when i pass ```what.png``` directly to the method it deletes the file, but my issue still remains since i don't know how to sepparate the filename from the whole URL. Any help here?

Comment: @stdunbar the latest version returns a response https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html#deleteObject-software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.DeleteObjectRequest-

Comment: @helloApp you should probably just save the path instead of the the full URL. What if you decided to add a custom domain name, or use CloudFront or something? If you really want to save the full URL, then just strip out `https://mybucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/` from the String. Look at the Java `String.replace()` method for that.

Comment: Yeah Mark B - I guessed based on the reference to `AmazonS3`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to use the [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html) class.  Something like:

```
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("https://mybucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/some/path/what.png");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println( "file is \""+ url.getFile() + "\"" );
```

output would be "/some/path/what.png".  You can remove the first "/" character to use for the key.

Answer (score 0):

Aws S3 is eventual consistent. You might delete object and s3 list that object in browser . So it take few seconds or less to delete .

Please refer this link

Comment: i waited more than 1 minute each time and file is still there

Comment: please check if versioning is enable in that bucket